# How to make padding responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design, padding, nav

I'm new to learning HTML and CSS and I really struggle with responsive design. I want to make my nav bar responsive and I think the best way is to edit the padding. If someone could give me some pointers I would really appreciate it.

```css
.navbar-left {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 36px 29px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

.navbar-center {
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 27px 311px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

.navbar-right {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 36px 29px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

.navbar-left:hover,
.navbar-right:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class="navbar-left" href="bio.html">About</a>
  <a class="navbar-left" href="resume.html">Resume</a>
</nav>

<nav>
  <a class="navbar-center" href="index.html">Sydnie Knowlton</a>
</nav>

<nav>
  <a class="navbar-right" href="works.html">Portfolio</a>
  <a class="navbar-right" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Generally use relative dimensions for padding.

Comment: Try using `display: inline-block`

Comment: Your units of padding are insanely high; a lot of devices won't be able to accommodate `311px` of padding. You really shouldn't need more than `20px` maximum for any fixed units of padding / margin, to allow decent display on mobile devices. What you probably want is something like `text-align: center` or `margin: 0 auto` to centre your text, and to make use of a column-based layout. You'll want [**media queries**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) for responsive design. Though unfortunately, as it stands, your question is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the width your three `nav` to `33.33%` and float them all to the left

don't rely on the side padding, use `width:50%` so the two links inside the `nav` fill all the space inside, and `text-align:center` to center the content

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  width: 33.33%;
  float: left;
}

.navbar-left {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 36px 2%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  width: 50%;
}

.navbar-center {
  float: left;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 27px 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-right {
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 36px 2%;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  width: 50%;
}

.navbar-left:hover,
.navbar-right:hover {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a class="navbar-left" href="bio.html">About</a>
  <a class="navbar-left" href="resume.html">Resume</a>
</nav>

<nav>
  <a class="navbar-center" href="index.html">Sydnie Knowlton</a>
</nav>

<nav>
  <a class="navbar-right" href="works.html">Portfolio</a>
  <a class="navbar-right" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
</nav>
```